# Text processing and exporting the content to an excel sheet

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed, regular-expression

I am trying to process a text file that contains multiple entries, I am interested in the Data filed of the text which consists of Name, Id, Size and Page83 ID.

```
Command: show PhysicalDisk name='IBM (721)'
Status: Success
Time: 2017-06-30 15:50:50,051 EST
Data:
  Name = IBM (721)
  Id = 0004fb0000180000d27ba1c974a69157
  Size (GiB) = 15.0
  Shareable = No
  Page83 ID = 360050768018385ace800000000000d6a
  Thin Provision = Yes
  VolumeGroup = Generic_SAN_Volume_Group @ Unmanaged FibreChannel Storage Array  [FibreChannel Volume Group]
  San Server = Unmanaged FibreChannel Storage Array  [Unmanaged FibreChannel Storage Array]
Command: show PhysicalDisk name='IBM (722)'
Status: Success
Time: 2017-06-30 15:50:53,636 EST
Data:
  Name = IBM (730)
  Id = 0004fb0000180000627770ff185759b6
  Size (GiB) = 100.0
  Shareable = No
  Page83 ID = 360050768018385ace800000000000d6b
  Thin Provision = Yes
  VolumeGroup = Generic_SAN_Volume_Group @ Unmanaged FibreChannel Storage Array  [FibreChannel Volume Group]
  San Server = Unmanaged FibreChannel Storage Array  [Unmanaged FibreChannel Storage Array]
```

I would like to process this text and put it in the excel sheet rows and columns.

[image]

This is just a sample output for two data fields. Also want to know how can we have this in place for "N number" of data fields.

Comment: If you want to create the excel sheet, I recommend using python with excel library. Or do you want to generate an `csv` file to be imported by excel? Then the country settings of excel are importent (field delimiter differ!). Or you can finally generate a tab-separated output to copy&paste into excel. WHat do you want?

Comment: For a simple comma-separated `csv` you could use something like `sed -n '/Name = /!d;N;N;N;N;y/\n/,/;s/, *Shareable = [^,]*//;s/[^,=]*= //g;p' yourfile`

Comment: @Phillops Thank you for the reply. Yes, I want to generate a csv file to be imported by Excel sheet.

Comment: PhillopsThanks a ton it worked like a charm!

Comment: So I'll add explanation to it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple comma-separated `csv` to be imported into excel you could use something like

```
sed -n '/Name = /!d
  N;N;N;N
  y/\n/,/
  s/, *Shareable = [^,]*//
  s/[^,=]*= //g;p' yourfile
```

The first line deletes all lines except the `Name =` ones. Continue only for those and append the four next lines to the buffer with `N`. The `y` command replaces the newlines between the lines with the separating commas. The first `s` command removes the `Shareable` line and the second one removes the part upto the `=` to leave only the value.
It will work for any number of rows. Text fields will be identified automatically without quotes in this case.